# General Advise on how to get ElementaryOS to run on 6 Core Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook

Can anybody provide some good sources on how to install ElementaryOS on a latest gen 6-Core Macbook Pro 15?

```
macOS Mojave
2,2 GhZ i7
16gb 2400 MhZ DDR4
Radeon 555x 4GB
Intel UHD 630
```

Any major hickups to be expected?

Comment: Please update the question with the specs of that computer.

Comment: done. thanks for pointing out.

Comment: The components you mention should work. However there may be things like WiFi or thunderbolt that may not work. [Here](https://gist.github.com/rwuwon/41f67dba2fb9ecc6e687ded25860d9c7) is a guide about the MacBook of 2017, I'm not sure if it's the same one but hope it helps.